# Adobe Flex para HTML

Tags: html, flex

Alguém sabe informar se há algum meio de converter MXML (Flex) para HTML?
Se sim, qual o meio para fazer essa conversão?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Não "tecnicamente"**.

No entanto existe um projeto chamado FlexJS que já deve ajustar bastante (não posso afirmar detalhes da compatibilidade e suporte do FlexJS para com o Flex):

- https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/FLEX/FlexJS+FAQ

Note que atualmente (02/05/2018) ele ainda se encontra na versão 0.8.0, ou seja pode não ter compatibilidade total com Flex e nem estar livre de BUGs, mas deve adiantar bastante coisa.

## Download

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/flexjs (instalar via NPM)
- https://flex.apache.org/download-flexjs.html (sources e binários para instalar manualmente)

Para instalar via npm use o comando (que torna bem mais fácil o uso disto) use o comando:

```
npm install flexjs -g
```

Os comandos disponiveis no CLI (terminal/cmd) após instalar serão `mxmlc`, `compc`, `asjsc`, `asjscompc`, `asnodec`, e `externc`.

Convertendo `.mxml`

```
mxmlc <caminho do seu .mxml PRINCIPAL>
```

Convertendo `.as`

```
asjsc <caminho do seu .as PRINCIPAL>
```